# Should @ViewChild work on directives

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

I'm trying to use @ViewChild to call a method on a directive... but it doesn't appear to work.  I get the following error:

```
TypeError: this.autoComplete.clear is not a function
```

It does however work on components, or when I switch the class decorator to @Component.

Alternatively, is there another recommended method for calling a method of a directive.

Comment: coulld you please share some plunker for this

Comment: There's no plunker required, it's a question in theory

Comment: This question doesn't provide enough information about what you try to accomplish. Please provide more code.

Comment: I really don't understand why, the title of the question and the first part of the first sentence are quite clear to me.  "Should @ViewChild work on directives, I'm trying to call a method of the directive via the ViewChild instance."

Answer (score 0):

You can't access `@ViewChild(MyDirective) someName;` in the constructor. `someName` is only set when `ngAfterViewInit()` is called.

**Update**

You might want to call

```
this.autoComplete.nativeElement.clear();
```

Comment: I understand this from the documentation, I trying to call a method of the directive via the ViewChild reference instance.  If it wasn't set yet I would get a error about it being undefined, as you can see from the error this is not the case.

Comment: I updated my answer but it's quite pointless to discuss without seeing the code that causes this error.